# Eclipse menu's line wrapper

Tags: eclipse, menu, word-wrap

Is there a word wrap for eclipse's menus like [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMYFi.png), so I don't always have to resize it?

Comment: What are we supposed to be seeing in that image?

Comment: @nitind Not all text is being shown because the phrase is bigger than the area

Comment: I don't know of any way to wrap the text, but you could easily dock the JUnit view so that it was as wide as your Eclipse window.